# Mapguide 2.6 with IIS on Windows 10

Tags: osgeo, mapguide

I got a new laptop with windows 10. I installed IIS on it.
But when I try to install mapguide 2.6 - I choose local IIS and .NET, the installer does nothing. I keep pressing OK, buy nothing happens.

I only need the web extension.

Help please...

Regards,
id

Comment: Ido, I am struggling with the same issue, have you solve it?

Comment: Kinda solved it.... Downgraded to win 7 sp1. :(

Comment: Have you asked on mapguide forum?

Comment: Couldn't post.. Did you?

Comment: No, I tried to install 2.5.2 version on Win10.On installation when I  come to IIS Configuration settings level I click Next button, it doesn't react and nothing happens.
The same behavior I get when I try install later version, mapguide 3.0.0

Comment: You can click on "next" in v. 3.1 :) otherwise you have to setup manually

Answer (score 0):

After some research I found solution on mapguide [forum](http://osgeo-org.1560.x6.nabble.com/Windows-10-td5221424.html).

1.Run installation file as amdinstrator, select manual installation.

2.IIS manual configuration, follow this [instructions](https://trac.osgeo.org/mapguide/wiki/ConfigureGuide24Windows).